# Working of a desert cooler?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

Does level of water have any effect of the capacity of  cooling in a desert cooler ?
The fan rotate with a constant angular velocity   so how and why does the water level effect the coolness capacity of a cooler ?

Answer (score 0):

If the water in the cooler's reservoir falls too low, then the pump in it that draws water from the reservoir to keep the porous pads wet will start sucking air instead of water and it will be unable to keep them all wet- and the cooling capacity of the device will fall suddenly. This is why desert coolers have an automatic float valve in the reservoir to maintain a constant water level. As the water level does down from evaporation, the valve opens up and more water flows in.

Answer (score 0):

**Evaporation causes cooling!**

Lesser water to pump to the pads $\Rightarrow$ Lesser evaporation by taking heat from hot air or lesser cooling of air.